# While loop ignoring parameters

Tags: vbscript, while-loop

I am trying to create a loop that stops a number from incrementing whilst it is lower than another number, a simple `y<=x`, but for some reason it just keeps going.

```
iv = 0
While iv <= vIC
     oExcel.Cells(1,1).value= vURL & iv
     oExcel.Cells(iv,2).value= vFileName & iv
     oExcel.Cells(iv,3).value= vIC
     iv = iv + 1
Wend
```

Comment: what's the value of vIC?

Comment: I replaced the While loop with 

    For count = iv to vIC

which seems to have fixed the issue

Comment: then delete this question, please, or add your solution as an answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your input is a string, so comparing an integer to it always produces the result `False`. To avoid this you need to [convert the string to an integer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ck4c5842%28v=vs.84%29.aspx):

```vb
iv = 0
While iv <= CLng(vIC)
    oExcel.Cells(1,1).value= vURL & iv
    oExcel.Cells(iv,2).value= vFileName & iv
    oExcel.Cells(iv,3).value= vIC
    iv = iv + 1
Wend
```

or use a [`For`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa3hh43e%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) loop which implicitly converts string arguments to integers:

```vb
For iv = 0 To vIC
    oExcel.Cells(1,1).value= vURL & iv
    oExcel.Cells(iv,2).value= vFileName & iv
    oExcel.Cells(iv,3).value= vIC
Next
```